# Flutter Outline View - "Nothing to show"

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

Hi has anyone already tried the new "Flutter Outline"-View?

I only see "Nothing to show" what I do wrong? Has anyone an idea?

[image]

Comment: What is it supposed to do ?

Comment: Hi @Darky please take a look here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/lKtTQ-45kc4

Comment: easy way https://stackoverflow.com/a/60274203/11404883

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: the below was the solution for the time. It seems this started to happen again recently and the solution is different. Please check the highly voted answer below for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61165205/679553

---

As I can tell from the Gitter chat, you are under the alpha channel, because you probably installed Flutter SDK through the IntelliJ plugin (this is a [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1828)).

Open a terminal/command window and type `flutter channel`. You'll see that you are in the alpha channel, which is actually abandoned. You need to be in the dev channel, but for some reason switching from alpha to dev does not work. Do this:

```
flutter channel master
flutter doctor
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
flutter channel
```

This should tell you that you are in dev channel. Now restart IntelliJ and try again.

If it still won't work, maybe you are on Windows like me? I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1827) about that.

Comment: @AnkurShah feel free to edit it, or point me to the up to date answer so I can edit it myself.

Comment: after restarting the android studio don't forget to run the application to see the tree

Answer (score 79):

Click to red restart dart analysis server button. It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

From my experience, hold Ctrl/Command and click on that widget to activate your FLutter Outline.

Answer (score 4):

right click in the file and select 'reformat code with dartfmt' it will format your code and then left click in the file and select dart outline.

Answer (score 2):

just run

> `flutter pub upgrade`
>   it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Hover mouse pointer over any class/property, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard.
You can see all of the items in the Flutter Outline.

[image: Flutter Outline].

Comment: I never get screen of this kind in my vscode! Please help!

Comment: This is Android Studio feature. You can not find this in VsCode.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. What I did is just went to the 'main.dart' file, the outline for the main file appeared, and then switch back to the current file and the outline worked. I do this every time and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, open Dart Analysis from the bottom tab and then click on **Restart Dart Analysis Server** icon (the red refresh icon). Now, reopen the Flutter Outline. This should fix the issue.

[Screenshot of Dart Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yULv3.png)