# Flutter Outline Shows "Nothing to show" in android studio

Tags: flutter

I am trying to extract a Widget via Flutter Outline, but I am facing below problem in Android Studio.

> Flutter Outline Shows  "Nothing to show"

[image]

After running

```
flutter doctor -v
```

It shows:

[image]

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 426, accepted):

Move the mouse to any widget and Press `Ctrl` (or `⌘ command` on macOS)  and click on that widget.

After this step, your `Flutter Outline` will be enabled and showing widget tree

Comment: It goes to another file where this class(widget class) located.

Comment: @MdMahmudulIslam after this you can close that class :)

Comment: A slight better option might be to ctrl + click any widget declaration `class YourWidget extend Something` on that file, then a tooltip of its usage will be shown. Just press esc to close the tooltip, and I hope the outline is now working, At least you didn't have to open and close the widget source code.

Comment: Press `cmd` instead of `ctrl` on mac

Comment: Mac: Command + Click on any widget indeed works.

Answer (score 77):

Click to red dart analysis server button, hopefully it will work

[image]

Answer (score 46):

**MacOS**: command + click on widget.

**Windows**: ctrl + click on widget.

*If they do **not** work, do not worry!* Follow these easy steps:

1. Click Dart Analysis (*on below part of Android Studio*)
2. You can see refresh button right side of Dart Analysis
3. Click it, **done!**

> *You can see image, click it:*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have same issues.

I just restart IntelliJ/Android studio and every time it's enough.

Comment: sadly this was the only thing which worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Enable this then the outline will work:

[image: An image showing the GUI with a target-like button highlighted]

Comment: Works for me, easier than restarting android studio, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

go to project directory on terminal by hitting,
`cd project_directory`
 then,

> flutter pub upgrade

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. After entering this command in the terminal, just restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

1. click on a widget to select one
2. press control and click the widget again (you will be directed to widget class)
3. go back to the first window and the outline should be displayed